# Summing chunks of columns - row wise - in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

With the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ProbeGenes' : ['1431492_at Lipn', '1448678_at Fam118a','1452580_a_at Mrpl21'],
                   '(5)foo.ID.LN.x1' : [20.3, 25.3,3.1],
                   '(5)foo.ID.LN.x2' : [130, 150,173],        
                   '(5)foo.ID.LN.x3' : [1.0, 2.0,12.0],         
                   '(3)bar.ID.LN.x1' : [1,2,3],
                   '(3)bar.ID.LN.x2' : [4,5,6],        
                   '(3)bar.ID.LN.x3' : [7,8,9]        
                   })


new_cols = df.pop("ProbeGenes").str.split().apply(pd.Series)
new_cols.columns = ["Probe","Gene"]
df = df.join(new_cols)
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-2:] + cols[:-2]
df = df[cols]
df
```

I can make the following data frame:

```
          Probe     Gene  (5)bar.ID.LN.x1  (5)bar.ID.LN.x2  (5)bar.ID.LN.x3  \
0    1431492_at     Lipn                1                4                7
1    1448678_at  Fam118a                2                5                8
2  1452580_a_at   Mrpl21                3                6                9

   (3)foo.ID.LN.x1  (3)foo.ID.LN.x2  (3)foo.ID.LN.x3
0             20.3              130                1
1             25.3              150                2
2              3.1              173               12
```

Notice that the data frame contain two chunks (named `foo` and `bar`), in turns each chunk contain `x1,x2,x3`. What I want to do is to sum up the values within each chunk resulting in this data frame:

```
          Probe     Gene  foo   bar
     1431492_at     Lipn  151.3 12
     1448678_at  Fam118a  177.3 15
   1452580_a_at   Mrpl21  188.1 18
```

The actual data can contain more than two chunk names. And each chunk will contain 2 or 3 members (`x1,x2` or `x1,x2,x3`).

The chunk name can be captured with the following regex `/\(\d+\)(\w+)\..*/`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to get started to find such "chunks":

```
   chunks = set([re.split('\(\d+\)',i)[1].split('.')[0] for i in df.columns if '.' in i])

for each_chunk in chunks:
        column_name = '%s' %each_chunk
        df[column_name] = df[[i for i in df.columns if each_chunk in i]].sum(axis=1)

## -- End pasted text --

In [1298]: df.head()
Out[1298]: 
          Probe     Gene  (3)bar.ID.LN.x1  (3)bar.ID.LN.x2  (3)bar.ID.LN.x3  \
0    1431492_at     Lipn                1                4                7   
1    1448678_at  Fam118a                2                5                8   
2  1452580_a_at   Mrpl21                3                6                9   

   (5)foo.ID.LN.x1  (5)foo.ID.LN.x2  (5)foo.ID.LN.x3    foo  bar  
0             20.3              130                1  151.3   12  
1             25.3              150                2  177.3   15  
2              3.1              173               12  188.1   18
```

Benchmarks:

```
In [1266]: %timeit df[bar_cols].sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 476 µs per loop

In [1267]: %timeit df[[i for i in df.columns if 'bar' in i]].sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 483 µs per loop

In [1268]: %timeit df.filter(regex='foo').sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 483 µs per loop
```

Comment: Is there a way I can generalize that t for multiple chunks > 2? Rather than hard coding `foo_cols` and `bar_cols`?

Comment: something like this ? `df[[i for i in df.columns if 'search_word' in i]].sum(axis=1)` and loop across all such columns that you need.

Comment: I'm not sure timing this small DateFrame gives much value, will give more interesting results for for a larger example. :)

Comment: Completely agree, nevertheless. :)

Answer (score 2):

One option if the data size is small

```
df['foo'] = df.filter(regex='foo').sum(axis=1) # It will filter all the columns which has the word 'foo' in it
df['bar'] = df.filter(regex='bar').sum(axis=1)
```

Please dont use this, if your data size is larger than 10,000 rows. Generally summing up using `axis=1` is slow

Comment: how can I generalize that for multiple chunks > 2?

Comment: What would you suggest doing if you have > 10000 rows?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this for many columns, I would suggest using a MultiIndex rather than a dot seperated string:

```
In [11]: new_cols = df.pop("ProbeGenes").str.split().apply(pd.Series)  # do something with this later

In [12]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.map(lambda x: tuple(x.split("."))))

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
  (3)bar       (5)foo
      ID           ID
      LN           LN
      x1 x2 x3     x1   x2  x3
0      1  4  7   20.3  130   1
1      2  5  8   25.3  150   2
2      3  6  9    3.1  173  12

In [14]: df.loc[:, "(3)bar"].sum(axis=1)
Out[14]:
0    12
1    15
2    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The reason, as I should edit in, is this looks up the "(3)bar" in the Index, so you don't need to iterate through every column to see if it includes bar. You can clean up the MI e.g. remove/move the 3.